# Limit of $\sqrt[n]{n^k}$ for k $\in \mathbb{N}$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

So the title basically says what my question is I'm looking for a proof for the limit of the given sequence (title).

Comment: This is always $1$.

Comment: Yeah I would also guess that but how do I prove that rigorous?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp{\left(\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}\right)}=\exp{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}\right)}=\exp{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\exp{(0)}=1$$
Where I have used [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln{(n)}}{n}$. Then due to the continuity of $f(x)=x^k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The limit is just
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^k}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}\right)^k=1^k=1$$

Comment: But I don't know that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ converges to 1 if n goes to infinity. So how can I prove that?

Comment: For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\ge1$, we can write $n^{1/n}=1+a_n$ where $a_n\ge 0$.  Then from the binomial theorem, with $n>1$

$$n=(1+a_n)^n\implies n \ge \frac12 n(n-1)a_n^2\implies 0\le a_n\le \sqrt{\frac2{n-1}}$$Now apply the squeeze theorem>

Comment: @FoYoungArealLo That question has been asked [many times](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/115822). I'm sure you'll find an answer that suits you.